# Accordion links in Firefox broken?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, firefox

coding newbie here. I have been trying to create links within an accordion format using css, javascript and html. However, the links work for all browers except firefox. What am I doing wrong?`

```js
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
    acc[i].onclick = function(){
        this.classList.toggle("active");
        this.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("show");
  }
}
```

```css
button.accordion {
    background-color: #222222;
    color: #ffffff;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 18px;
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    text-align: left;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 15px;
    transition: 0.4s;
}

button.accordion.active, button.accordion:hover {
    background-color: #666666;
}

div.panel {
    padding: 0 18px;
    display: none;

    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

div.panel.show {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<button class="accordion">1. Item 1  &nbsp &nbsp <a href="http://google.com">link 1</a>  &nbsp &nbsp</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>
  Line 1<br \>
Line 2 <br \> <br \>

  </p>
</div>

<button class="accordion">1. Item 2  &nbsp &nbsp <a href="http://google.com">link 1</a>  &nbsp &nbsp</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>
  Line 1<br \>
Line 2 <br \> <br \>

  </p>
</div>
```

I have saved my code in JSFIDDLE.

https://jsfiddle.net/jrprgst2/

Comment: Seem to work for me in firefox. Define *"not working"* in more detail as in difference between existing behavior vs expected behavior

Comment: The embedded link in the code to google.com doesn't work on clicking it with Firefox - but works on all other browsers. Any idea why or what to do to fix it? Jquery accordion seems to break my other formatting. Any way this can be fixed using regular JavaScript?

Comment: jsfiddle code runs in an iframe and you can't load some sites in an iframe...google is one

Answer (score 0):

Try to use JQuery accordion instead of basic Javascript.

Here is an exemple that works in differents browsers:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Accordion</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $("#accordion").accordion({
      alwaysOpen: false,
      active: false,
      autoheight: false,
      clearStyle: true
    }).find('a').click(function(ev) {
      window.location.href = $(this).attr("href");
    });
  });
  </script>
  <style>
    .ui-accordion2-header {
      position: absolute;
      right: 10px;
      top: 10px;
      width: 345px;
    }

    .ui-accordion2-header a {
      width: auto;
      display: inline;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="accordion" class="ui-accordion2-group">
  <h3 data-sectionid="1">
    Section 1 <a href="https://www.google.com">link 1</a>
  </h3>
  <div>
    <p>Mauris mauris ante, blandit et, ultrices a, suscipit eget, quam.</p>
  </div>

  <h3 data-sectionid="2">
    Section 2 <a href="http://www.youtube.com">link 2</a>
  </h3>
  <div>
    <p>Mauris mauris ante, blandit et, ultrices a, suscipit eget, quam.</p>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The embedded link in the code to google.com doesn't work on clicking it with Firefox - but works on all other browsers. Any idea why or what to do to fix it? Jquery accordion seems to break my other formatting. Any way this can be fixed using regular JavaScript?

Comment: That's work for me in Firefox (version 44.0.1).
I have no idea to solve your problem with regular Javascript.